# PHP calculator, with 4 changeable options

Tags: php, calculator

Hey I've build this little calculator and thought I would share it so it would help more people :)
You just have to change the value for $opt variable to get different outputs.
If you have any comments or improvements feel free to add them.
When I will get some free time I will post more.

```
<?php
$opt = "Example 1";

$x;
$x1;

switch ($opt) {
      case "Example 1": 
           $keywords = array("add", "multiply", "apply");
           $values = array("2", "3", "4");
           break;
      case "Example 2":
           $keywords = array("multiply", "apply");
           $values = array("9", "5");
           break;
      case "Example 3":
           $keywords = array("apply");
           $values = array("1");
           break;
      case "Example 4":
           $keywords = array("divide", "substract", "apply");
           $values = array("2", "3", "8");
           break;
      default:
           echo "No valid example has been chosen";
           break;
}

$klen = count($keywords);
$klen -=1;
$x = $values[$klen];
echo "Apply " .$x. "\n";

$klen -=1;
$j =0;

foreach ($keywords as $i) {
   $x1 = $values[$j];
   $j +=1; 

    switch ($i) {
      case "add": 
           $x += $x1;
           echo "Add " .$x1. "\n";
           break;
      case "multiply":
           $x *= $x1;
           echo "Multiply " .$x1. "\n";
           break;
      case "divide":
           $x /=$x1;
           echo "Divide " .$x1. "\n";
           break;
      case "substract":
           $x -=$x1;
           echo "Substract " .$x1. "\n";
           break;
      case "apply":
           break;      
    }
}

    echo "The result is " .$x;    

?>
```

Comment: Welcome. Please use https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ if you need someone to review/comment on your code.

Comment: This site is for questions only. For code review [there is a dedicated site](https://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Will do. Thank u.

Comment: Welcome to SO. As mentioned, this site is in the question-answer format. However, question are welcome as well, if they bring their own answer with them. You could ask some question which many others could frequently ask and post your code you want to share as an answer to your own question. You may even accept your own answer. This is legit and welcome on SO. Questions/answers just have to be useful for other people looking for a solution on a similar problem. Read [ask] and [mcve] first, then think about how you can form a question fitting the requirements for a SO question.